# How to get the access token to register iOS device in Google API with Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, google-api-php-client

I am working on Firebase message implementation to my php project. I am able to get the token for Android device by using 
`$result = $this->guzzle->request('GET', 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=$key",$headers)`

How to do the same thing for iOS? I can't able to find the exact documentation for this.

Thanks,

Sai

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using Firebase FCM for  messaging and notification.

There are some instructions available here for iOS and Android:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Firebase FCM is replacing GCM and is the suggested approach for push notifications for Android.

Thanks,

Dinakaran